# Feedback form slider

Tags: jquery, css, forms, slider

I have used some code for feedback form that slides up.It placed in bottom.
I want to fix it in bottom like if i am scrolling page it will fix there.
Code for it i have used :

Div Code :

```
<div class="feedback">
  <a id="feedback_button">Feedback</a>

  <div class="form">
  <h2>Please Send Us Your Feedback</h2>
    <span class="status"></span>
    <textarea id="feedback_text"></textarea>
    <input type="button" value="Send" id="submit_form" />
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
.feedback{
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
.feedback a {
    display:block;
    height:20px;
    width:100px;
    text-align:center;
    background:red;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    outline:1px solid #a1a1a1;  
    padding:5px;
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer;

    /*Font*/
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:18px;
}

.feedback .form{
    clear:both;
    height:300px;
    width:450px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    background:#fff;
    padding:15px;
    display: none;
}
.feedback .form textarea{
    height:170px;
    width:400px;
    padding:5px;
}
.feedback .status{
    font-size:16px;
}
```

jquery :

```
(function ($j) {

  feedback_button = {

    onReady: function () {      
      this.feedback_button_click();
      this.send_feedback();
    },

    feedback_button_click: function(){
        $("#feedback_button").click(function(){
            $('.form').slideToggle();           
        });
    },

    send_feedback: function(){
        $('#submit_form').click(function(){
            if($('#feedback_text').val() != ""){

                $('.status').text("");

                $.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "./process_email.php",  
                    data: 'feedback=' + $('#feedback_text').val(),  
                    success: function(result,status) { 
                        //email sent successfully displays a success message
                        if(result == 'Message Sent'){
                            $('.status').text("Feedback Sent");
                        } else {
                            $('.status').text("Feedback Failed to Send");
                        }
                    },
                    error: function(result,status){
                        $('.status').text("Feedback Failed to Send");
                    }  
                });
            }
        });
    },


  };

  $j().ready(function () {
      feedback_button.onReady();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

Tell me how can i fix it in bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
.feedback{
    position:fixed;
    //left:0;
    bottom:0%;
    z-index: 99;
}
```

Comment: Its works.But in image slider it will goes behind image .How can i take it in front ?